# Adding benchmark lines to trend lines in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, charts, benchmarking, annotate, trendline

I created a chart with speed over time. I then added two trendlines using Excel.

**I would like to include a benchmark line - so in this case based on the trendlines - when does the speed reach 85%.**

I did this by adding lines -to the chart (highligted in yellow) but wondering if there's a more accurate way to do this. At the moment I'm eye-balling the mark and moving my mouse to get to 85% line...

[image: example chart]